# Can someone explain why :null_session still returns this error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm new to rails and having a tough time with the concept of protect_from_forgery, from what i understand this method uses :verify_authenticity_token to protect a route. The route I'm using this on is an API route; something like this:

```rb
class ApiController < ActionController::API
  protect_from_forgery with: :null, only: %i[execute]

  before_action :validate_csrf_token, only: %i[execute]

  def execute
  # action here
  end

  private

  def validate_csrf_token
     return true unless request.post?
     token = request.headers['X-CSRF-Token']
     if token.blank? || !valid_authenticity_token?(token, nil)
       render json: { error: 'Invalid CSRF token' }, status: :unprocessable_entity
     end
  end
end
```

I also have another controller which i use to get my token from my rails app

```rb
class CsrfTokenController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def index
    render json: { csrf_token: form_authenticity_token }
  end
end
```

which i send to my ApiController. the first issue i encounter is this error

```
HTTP Origin header (http://localhost:3020) didn't match request.base_url (http://localhost:3000)
```

secondly when i perform post requests the token i sent is invalid

```
error: "Invalid CSRF token"
```

i can confirm that the token request is the one being sent back when i print the variable.

Is there something i'm missing here, or am i understanding :null_session all wrong?

Edit:

Updated due to incorrect method mentioned for protecting route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the CSRF protection does is give you a degree of certainty that the request originated from a page rendered by you own server. That's great for classical apps and APIs that are just meant to feed your own Single Page Application with JSON. But if you're creating an API that is designed to be used cross domain and also possibly by server based clients the Rails CSRF protection is irrelevant and actually completely opposed to those requirements.

> method uses form_authenticity_token to protect a route

No not really. The way this works is that a unique token is rendered into the HTML of the page (forms and the meta tag) and the same token is stored in the session.

Since the session is stored in an encrypted cookie we have a reasonable degree of certainty that it hasn't be tampered with.

When the user then submits the form your controller checks for a token in the requests body or the `X-CSRF-Token` header and raises an exception unless it matches the value provided by the session cookie. This token should only be valid for a single request cycle.

Since cookies are single domain by default you shouldn't actually expect this to work when you're sending a request from a different origin.

See:

- https://medium.com/rubyinside/a-deep-dive-into-csrf-protection-in-rails-19fa0a42c0ef
- https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

Comment: Note that this is a simplied discription of how the original CSRF protection worked. In Rails 5 per form authenticity tokens were introduced so the session actually contains multiple tokens.

Comment: sorry i meant :verify_authencity_token as the method which filters unverified request. form_authenticity_token generates the token.

Comment: I'm guessing this means protect_from_forgery is pretty much useless for controllers used for cross-domain requests, and i'd have to rely on other mechanisms that don't rely on sessions? Do you have any resources you can share where i can read up more on this?

Comment: Yeah, thats a pretty fair conclusion. Securing API's isn't an easy topic and there unfortunately isn't one single clear cut solution. https://blog.eq8.eu/article/rails-api-authentication-with-spa-csrf-tokens.html

Comment: https://rorsecurity.info/portfolio/cross-site-request-forgery-and-rails

Comment: thanks a lot for taking the time to respond